# How to reduce build time of 'browserify-rails' gem?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, browserify

I am working on project that will use Reactjs on top off rails application.
So i set up my project following this link
[Set up Rails with React and Es6](https://github.com/manjarb/rails_es6_react_starter_kit/blob/master/README.md)

Everything is working fine but i change my `bundle.js` to this

```
require('./main');
```

Then inside `main.js` i have this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM  from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

/*Import Component*/

import NotFound from './components/NotFound';

/*
 *
 * Routes
 *
 * */

var routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={NotFound}/>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routes , document.querySelector('#main'));
```

So inside my component file (`/components/NotFound.js`)
I have this

```
import React from 'react';

var NotFound = React.createClass({
    render : function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Not found</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

export default NotFound;
```

It can be displayed smoothly but the problem is
when i change some code inside my component file (in this case `/components/NotFound.js`) then refresh the page.
It took around 3 Seconds for just 1 line of code that i added to my component file.

So this is so painful because it took a huge amount of time just for edit a few line of code.

So anyone know how can i reduce the build time to be less than this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you looked into [browserify-incremental](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails#browserify-incremental)? It wasn't mentioned in the setup you referenced.

Comment: @cartant Yes, i put this `config.browserify_rails.use_browserifyinc = true` in my application.rb but i still use 3 secs for the build time.